# Android Java Occur a method event

Tags: java, android, events, methods, load

Hello I want that my methods work instantly when the user enters the application.
For now I have an onClick event in my xml which activates so to say my methods(this works).

the xml:

```
            <TextView
            android:id="@+id/cd_start"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingBottom="0dp"
            android:text="time"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textSize="21sp"
            android:onClick="dateEnd"/>
```

and Main Activity.java

```
String dateStopKukuk = "21 Dec 2015";

private void displayDateEnd(String etime) {
    TextView priceTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.cd_start);
    priceTextView.setText(etime);
}

public void dateEnd(View v) {
    displayDateEnd(dateStopKukuk);
}
```

Comment: Override onCreate method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: I added a comments to explain you this code.

Try this:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener 
{

    // onClick method is called when one of view is clicked. (you must use setOnClickListener on this View to inform system to call this)
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        // check if clicked view is cd_start
        if(v.getId() == R.id.cd_start)
        {
             // true cd_start is clicked
             displayDateEnd(dateStopKukuk);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); // REQUIRED!!! When you don't add this your app will be crash.
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); // sets activity_main as layout (if you use different name of layout replace activity_name with your layout name)
        findViewById(R.id.cd_start).setOnClickListener(this); // finds view with cd_start id and sets click listener. When this view is clicked system calls onClick method.
        // and now your code what do you want to do when activity is creating.
    }

    String dateStopKukuk = "21 Dec 2015";

    private void displayDateEnd(String etime) {
        TextView priceTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.cd_start);
        priceTextView.setText(etime);
    }

    /* You don't need dateEnd method now */
}
```

XML:

```
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/cd_start"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingBottom="0dp"
            android:text="time"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textSize="21sp"
            /> <!-- You don't need android:onClick -->
```

In your activity.

I hope it helped you.

Comment: So do I have to remove the onClick in my xml?

Comment: @Mrx No you don't need to remove onClick in xml. You must override onCreate method. This method is called only once when activity is creating. You must call super.onCreate to application works. And use setContentView to set layout. For example: if your layout is called activity_main.xml use this: `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);`
I'm editing answer now.

Comment: Thank you so far, so I did paste my methods on but i got some errors which say cannot resolve method... cannot resolve view ...

Comment: I will edit my answer. Are you beginner in android. Am I right?

Comment: Yes pretty much I started a few weeks ago and now I am testing some stuff out:)

Comment: Ok now I just have one error message at the last bracers '}'
which tell 'class' or interaface expected

Comment: I will accept this as ok for now ill have a look later again thank you so far